# Require documentation for Typescript interfaces, enums, namespaces, etc

Tags: typescript, eslint, tslint

I have used TSLint in the past to require documentation things like interfaces, enums, and other things that don't exist in Javascript:

```
"completed-docs": [
            true,
            {
                ...
                "enums": {
                    "visibilities": ["all"]
                },
                "enum-members": {
                    "visibilities": ["all"]
                },
                "functions": {
                    "visibilities": ["all"]
                },
                "interfaces": {
                    "visibilities": ["all"]
                },
                "namespaces": {
                    "visibilities": ["all"]
                },
                "types": {
                    "visibilities": ["exported"]
                },
                "variables": {
                    "visibilities": ["exported"]
                }
```

Given TSLint is deprecated, I want to use Eslint, but i can't find anyway to require documentation on Typescript structures... I can require documentation on classes, methods, etc via this rule:

```
"jsdoc/require-jsdoc": ["error", {"require": {
      "FunctionExpression": true,
      "ClassDeclaration": true,
      "MethodDefinition": true,
      "ArrowFunctionExpression": true,
      "ClassExpression": true
    }}],
```

But there is no support in that rule to require documentation for Typescript structures. Any way to do this with Eslint (without using the TSLint plugin?)

Comment: If you haven't looked into this, maybe this can be of use to you: [`require-jsdoc`](https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-jsdoc#eslint-plugin-jsdoc-rules-require-jsdoc) in [eslint-plugin-jsdoc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-jsdoc).I haven't used it.

Comment: I am using it as I point out in my question - my issue is that it covers JS structures, but not TS ones...

Comment: Sorry I misread it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is solved [here](https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-jsdoc/issues/496#issuecomment-591204300), you should:

> Add the AST types to the contexts option to the rule.
>
> You'll have to consult a list of TypeScript AST to find the types or
>   use a @typescript-eslint/parser-supporting AST explorer like
>   astexplorer.net (there is also ts-ast-viewer.com and that is
>   TS-specific, but it is not using @typescript-eslint/parser which
>   adapts TS interfaces into the AST needed by ESLint and which we are
>   using).
>
> So, for example:
>
> ```
> 'jsdoc/require-jsdoc': ['error', {contexts: ['TSInterfaceDeclaration', 'TSTypeAliasDeclaration', 'TSEnumDeclaration']}]
> ```